# Colab throws errors when attempting to apply a SeparableConv2D layer in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, convolution, tf.keras

While learning Tensorflow 2.0 and experimenting  with various structures I came across SeparableConv2D.  I attempted to re-create a simple stack of VGG blocks that used the separable layers instead of standard convolutional layers, but Colab throws an error every time I attempt to add additional separable convolutions.
Here's the first block of code:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
model.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=2))
```

The error that Colab returns is:

```
File "<ipython-input-17-797462afefac>", line 3
model.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've reviewed the documentation and compared to an actual example from Francois Chollet's book on Keras and Tensorflow, but neither of them have given me any insight as to why this isn't working as it should.  Does anyone know the correct syntax for these layers which will allow me to continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a bracket :

```
model.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
```

should be

```
model.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)) )
```

Note the `)` at the end.